# Magento 2.3.3 - Import Newsletter subscribers along with email, Name, Type, Website, Store, Store view from CSV

Tags: php, magento2.3, import, newsletter

I run a multi website and store setup, on PHP 7.1

I'm trying to import newsletter subscribers from a CSV as follows, which is in a CSV file called **subscribers-import.csv** in the root dir.

[image]

I'm using the following code in a file called **import.php** in the root dir.

```
<?php
  ob_start();
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$store_id = 1;
$csv_filepath = "subscribers-import.csv";
$csv_delimiter = ',';
$csv_enclosure = '"';
$magento_path = __DIR__;

$params = $_SERVER;

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);

$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$websiteId =  $obj->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')
    ->getStore()
    ->getWebsiteId();

$customerAccountManagement =$obj
    ->create('Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface');

$_subscriberFactory = $obj->create('Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriberFactory');


if (($handle = fopen("subscribers-import.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        // email Id
        $emailId =  $data[1];
       /* customer */
        if($customerAccountManagement->isEmailAvailable($emailId , $websiteId)){
            echo $emailId ."<br/>";
            $_subscriberFactory->create()->subscribe($emailId );
        }else{
            echo $emailId ."Register <br/>";
            $customerFactory = $obj->get('Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory');
            $customer=$customerFactory->create();
            $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
            $customer->loadByEmail($emailId );// load customer by email address
            if($customer->getId()){
                $_subscriberFactory->create()->subscribeCustomerById($customer->getId());
            }

        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
 ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Right now it **only imports the email ID**, as shown as follows.

[image]

How can I get it to import the rest of the data in the CSV like

> **Type | Customer First Name | Customer Last Name | Status | Website Store | Store View**

Answer (score 0):

Free [Extension](https://github.com/perrymarkg/m2-reviews-importer)

**You Got Value in $data Array Like This :-**

```
$data[0] = id
$data[1] = email
$data[2] = type
$data[3] = customer first name
$data[4] = customer last name
$data[5] = status
$data[6] = website
$data[7] = store
$data[8] = store view
```

Comment: Sorry, how do I use this?

Comment: Try This Extension https://github.com/perrymarkg/m2-reviews-importer

Comment: This is for reviews.